# Calculate a graph of motion for a projectile

Tags: projectile-motion

I would like to produce a program that can take in a 2D velocity vector, a projectile's mass (projectile should be modelled as a particle in that all of the mass is concentrated at a single point, although ideally I would like to take into account air resistance so I'm not exactly sure what you call it), it's starting point and will then output a function which is the route it takes in motion.

It should take into account air resistance.

My idea was that you could continuously compute the horizontal and vertical positions of the ball as a function of time, start point, starting velocities and the mass of the projectile. Assuming we are starting at point `(0, 0)`, I want a function `f(t, x, y, h, v, m)` that will return x<sub>t</sub> and y<sub>t</sub>. Where t is the current time, x is the starting x point, y is the starting y point, h is initial the horizontal velocity, v is the initial vertical velocity (both in m/s <sup>2</sup>) and m is the mass. x<sub>t</sub> is the x coordinate at time t, and y<sub>t</sub> is the y coordinate at time t. It will keep running until y<sub>t</sub> `= 0`.

Assuming you can calculate t<sub>f</sub> (time at which the sphere hits the ground), I would think you could generate a list of coordinates by doing what I described above every k seconds until n * k reaches a point where (n + 1) * k would be > t<sub>f</sub>, and so instead you calculate it for t<sub>f</sub> and end the program.

I'm just not sure exactly what function this would be, and also if this is the best method?

EDIT: It makes more sense to model it as a circle. But then you also need to take into account its radius?

Comment: $d=v_it+{1\over2}at^2$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: First of all, it makes no sense for a point mass to be affected by air resistance. I don't see why you would care anyway since classical forces essentially act on the center of mass of an object anyway. But, for an arbitrary figure, this motion while is resolvable by hand is complex enough to be left to be done by the computers. Approximating (or assuming) the object to be a sphere makes it way better, but someone with a larger attention span than me will have to write it out.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Do you mean a circle instead of a sphere?

Comment: I mean the object being a sphere @FJ

Comment: @Certainlynotadog I was asking about 2D modelling

Comment: That would still be better than an arbitrary shape.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog How is a circle arbitrary?

Comment: Er, when did I say that? I meant to convey that a circle would be easier to build a function for than a general/arbitrary shape. (which is obvious)

Comment: then what you look for isn't useful.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog I asked if you meant a circle, and you suggested a 3D shape.......

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I don't know why you commented a single formula and expected it to help. It may make up part of the solution but clearly isn't a full solution.

Comment: it is if you know what it means, it's the distance under acceleration formula.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Again, I know what it is but that alone doesn't come close to solving the problem.

Comment: apply it to each leg of the separation of forces ... you get a path...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee “It should take into account air resistance.” The formula in your original comment doesn’t.

Comment: a is acceleration, just add acceleration terms ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee “Just add acceleration terms” doesn’t work with that formula unless those accelerations are constant. Air resistance is typically modeled as being proportional to velocity (for low speeds) or proportional to the square of the velocity, neither of which is constant.

Comment: add one for each acceleration ... also you can use average accelerati9n and get a rough answer on where it will hit ...  ${1\over 2}at^2$ is average change in velocity multiplied by time...